# Setup Project for two applications that share dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

I am using Visual Studio 2008

I have two applications (AppA and AppB) that I what to be installed using one msi-installer.
Both applications have reference AppC.

This is what I did:

1. I created Setup Project
2. I created two subfolders inside of Application Folder (AppA and AppB)
3. I added Project Output for AppA into related subfolder
4. I added Project Output for AppB into related subfolder

Problem: AppC did not appear in subfolder for AppB. It looks like dependency can only appear once.

Could please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: When talking about InstallShield's family of products, "Project Output" does not include references. You need to include them manually in the target locations (or use dependency scanning - may not be available in the version you are using).

Comment: @StingyJack: I changed my quetion to make it more specific. VS added AppC dependency into first subfolder (AppA) but refused to add it once again for AppB.

Comment: What Installer technology are you using?

Comment: @StingyJack: VS2008 has template called Setup Project

Comment: Thats an important difference as its the last release before switching to ISLE. Do you have AppC referenced by both AppA and AppB's projects?

Comment: @StingyJack: Yes, I have AppC referenced by both projects.

Comment: I'm out of practice with the old VS installer, and don't have that version available any longer to help. Sorry.

Comment: @StingyJack: I have been told that Setup Project in VS2010 is pretty much the same. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: @StingyJack: I also have an idea that I should do what I want using merge modules. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding "Primary Output from AppC" specifically to each of the application folders. This version of VS Setup does not appear to detect that the same dependency needs to be included in two application folders.

There are a lot of recorded problems with the VS Setup and Deployment project, especially in regards to dependency detection. Also consider that MS has stopped shipping this project type, and has chosen the ISLE as its replacement (I would recommend using WIX instead - its free and is a more modern toolset when compared to Flexera's offerings).

A merge module is overkill for a single assembly. If you had a package of assemblies that need things like COM exposure or other group behavior things that you dont want to repeat (and possibly get wrong), then a merge module is more appropriate.